# Magento 2 - How to add custom customer attributes to sales order API?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, rest-api

I have created custom attributes in the `customer` table.

I want to add those attributes in order API. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will get customer_id from the order and from customer_id you can get customer attribute then set that attribute in order api.

Try this blog it will return your custom attribute in order API response https://www.atwix.com/development/adding-custom-attribute-to-api-response-in-magento-2/

If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: I have seen this but it is not so clear to me. In the blog's example of `extension_attributes.xml`, there is `<attribute code="customer_feedback" type="string" />`, do I actually need to have `customer_feedback` column in `sales_order` table? Because I don't want to actually create that column in `sales_order` table since that column exists in ` customer` table. Any suggestions/help will be appreciated. Thank you.